# How to compare two dates with momentJS ignoring the year value?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Let's say a term starts from 1 November 2015 to 3 January 2016.  The sample dates to compare are as follows ('YYYY-MM-DD'):

```
2015-10-12 = false
2015-11-01 = true (inclusive)
2015-12-20 = true
2015-01-03 = true (inclusive)
2016-01-30 = false
2017-11-21 = true (year is ignored)
2010-12-20 = true (year is ignored)
```

Is there a way that I can achieve this result with MomentJS?

Comment: the simplest solution would be to test if the target date is within bounds, if it is, return true, otherwise set the year of the target date (you may want to use a copy of it) to 2015, test it's within the bounds, if it is, return true, otherwise, set the year to 2016, test it's within the bounds, if it is, return true, otherwise return false

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  As I'm using it in a calendar, I would have do the comparison multiple times for each user inquiry.  I'm just wondering if there is another way of doing it.

Comment: There was an anwser using `'____-MM-DD'` format to ignore the year and `isBetween()` for the comparison. I wonder why that person deleted his post, the solution works. I tested the code before it was deleted: http://pastebin.com/NSJVRdxY

Comment: @ShanShan ... I saw that, too, and was wondering if that would actually work. I thought it would only work is there was no different year in the boundaries. If it would actually work with different years, the method would always return a positive result. I assumed, that is why it was taken down

Comment: @ShanShan It's because it wasn't correctly handling dates in january. Ignoring the year would mean that 2017-01-03 defaults to 2015-01-03 which is not in the range of 2015-11-01 to 2016-01-03. I fixed it though and the updated answer is below.

Comment: @Shashank: ah, my bad ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3xxe3Lg0/

```
var moments = [
'2015-10-12',
'2015-11-01',
'2015-12-20',
'2015-01-03',
'2016-01-30',
'2017-11-21',
'2010-12-20'];

var boundaries = [moment('2015-11-01').subtract(1, 'days'),moment('2016-01-03').add(1, 'days')];

for (var i in moments){
    res = moments[i] + ': ';
    if (
        moment(moments[i]).year(boundaries[0].year()).isBetween(boundaries[0], boundaries[1]) ||
        moment(moments[i]).year(boundaries[1].year()).isBetween(boundaries[0], boundaries[1])

       ){
        res += 'true';
    }
    else{
        res += 'false';
    }
    $('<div/>').text(res).appendTo($('body'));
}
```

EDIT: with a tiny change it would even work, if the upper boundary was not one but two (or more) years ahead from the lower one.

```
for (var i in moments){
    res = moments[i] + ': ';
    if (
        moment(moments[i]).year(boundaries[0].year()).isBetween(boundaries[0], boundaries[1]) ||
        moment(moments[i]).year(boundaries[0].year()+1).isBetween(boundaries[0], boundaries[1])

       ){
        res += 'true';
    }
    else{
        res += 'false';
    }
    $('<div/>').text(res).appendTo($('body'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/), but kind of messy.

```
function isWithinTerm(dateString) {
  var dateFormat = '____-MM-DD', // Ignore year, defaults to current year
      begin = '2015-10-31', // Subtract one day from start of term
      end = '2016-01-04', // Add one day to finish of term
      mom = moment(dateString, dateFormat); // Store to avoid re-compute below
  return mom.isBetween(begin, end) || mom.add(1, 'y').isBetween(begin, end);
}
```

The reason I'm adding a year as an optional check is just for the January case since January of 2015 is obviously not between November 2015 and January 2016. I know it's kind of hacky, but I couldn't think of any simpler way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the '__' syntax in momentJS.  I'm not aware of it until now, could be useful in my other date manipulation :)